# std::sort error using custom classes

Tags: c++, sorting

I have looked through stackoverflow and added an overload operator to hopefully make it work with sort. Though I still get an explosion of an error saying something is wrong with sort.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>

class Student
{
private:
  std::string name_;
  int number_;
  std::vector<int> grades_;
  const int num_courses_;

  static std::string gen_name() {
    return std::to_string(rand());
  }
  static int gen_number() {
    return rand() % (201600000 - 201100000 + 1) + 201100000;
  }
  static int gen_grade() {
    return rand() % (100 - 70 + 1) + 70;
  }
  double compute_average() {
    int marks = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = grades_.begin(); i != grades_.end(); i++, count++){
      marks += *i;
    }
    return static_cast<double>(marks) / count;
  }

public:
  Student() : name_(gen_name()), number_(gen_number()), num_courses_(5)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_courses_; ++i) {
      grades_.push_back(gen_grade());
    }
  }

  double getAvg() {
    return compute_average();
  }
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Student& s) {
    os << "Name = " << s.name_ << "\tNumber = " << s.number_ << "\tAvg = " << s.compute_average();
    return os;
  }

  std::string getName() {
    return name_;
  }
  void print_grades(std::ostream& os) const
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_courses_; ++i) {
      os << grades_[i] << ", ";
    }
  }
  bool operator < (const Student& str) const
  {
    return (name_ < str.name_);
  }
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  if (argc == 2){
    int numbOfStudents = atoi(argv[1]);
    std::vector<Student> studentVec;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbOfStudents; i++){
      studentVec.push_back(Student());
    }

    std::sort(studentVec.begin(), studentVec.end());
    for (std::vector<Student>::iterator xi = studentVec.begin(); xi != studentVec.end(); xi++) {
      std::cout << *xi << std::endl;
    }

  }
  else{
    std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " {numb} " << std::endl;
  }
  return 0
}
```

The error comes when I run sort (I know it's sort since if I comment it out, it works properly). With the error code

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/algorithm:62:0,
             from main.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void   std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:1884:70:   required from ‘void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:1970:55:   required from ‘void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]’
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:4685:72:   required from ‘void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Student*, std::vector<Student> >]’
main.cpp:79:50:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_algo.h:1851:17: error: use of deleted function ‘Student& Student::operator=(Student&&)’
    *__first = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__val);
```

I searched earlier which helped me get to the result of adding a '<' overload, though I still get an error. Can anyone help point out where the mistake is? Thank you. (I compile using g++ --std=c++11)

Comment: In a nutshell: `num_courses_` is const, therefore `sort` can't change it.

Comment: Holy, it was that easy. Thank you so much. I feel so stupid now...

Comment: There should be a semicolon after `return 0` in line 83.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the member variable `const int num_courses_;` is const, which means it must be set in the initializer list of the constructor.

num_courses_ can't be set by the copy assignment operator `Student& Student::operator=(Student&&)`, so it prevent the compiler from generating the copy assignment operator for that class. Since there's no copy assignment operator available, and the std::sort function needs it to work, the compilation fails and complains about the copy assignment operator not being available.

Simply remove the `const` and declare the variable as `int num_courses_` and your code should work.